# deploy physical server from vmware template (linux)

Tags: centos, vmware-esxi

I've been looking at replacing several aging servers, and to that end, I've prepared a vmware template to act as a standardized base. However, it's now become a requirement that I be able to deploy this standardized image to physical servers as well, and from what I understand, I'd need to write a kickstarter to have any sort of capability to deploy to physical servers and have all the configurations and such that I've already set up in place.

So my question is, is there any way I can take an existing template in vmware and apply it to a blank server?

Comment: No. Not really...

Answer (score 0):

This is linux - so you can just `dd` hard disk. Anyway you will have to reconfigure something to support hardware.

BTW, why you don't want just install ESXI on hardware server and run a single VM (deployed from template)? The performance is almost the same, and there are much less problems with hardware support.

Comment: that's a good idea